# String em Struct - Linguagem C

Tags: c

Não consigo usar uma string dentro da struct que eu criei.
Sem essa string, o programa dá uns warnings mas funciona normalmente.

*PS: Só preciso de ajuda com o erro da string, pois a mensagem de erro ficou extensa.*

Segue o código em seguida a mensagem de erro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COCA_COLA_250 3,50
#define COCA_COLA_1000 8,00
#define FANTA_LARANJA_250 3,00
#define FANTA_LARANJA_1000 7,50
#define GUARANA_ANTARTIDA_250 3,50
#define GUARANA_ANTARTIDA_1000 8,00

#define MARACUJA_250 3,50
#define LIMONADA_250 3,00
#define LARANJA_250 3,00

struct refri
{
    char pedido_um [] = "Cola Cola";
    char pedido_dois [20];
    char pedido_tres [20];

    int escolha;
    int tamanho;
    int quantidade_unidade;

} pedido_refrigerante;

int refrigerante (int *preco_total)
{
    int refri_pequeno = 250;
    int refri_medio = 1;

        printf("+===============================REFRIGERANTES==============================+\n");
        printf("|---------------------- Escolha o(s) refrigerante(s): ---------------------|\n");
        printf("|------- 1 > Coca Cola \t 2 > Guarana Antartida \t 3 > Fanta Laranja ------|\n");
        printf("+==========================================================================|\n");
        printf("|------------------------------ 0 > Cancelar ------------------------------|\n");
        printf("+==========================================================================+\n");

            scanf("%d", &pedido_refrigerante.escolha);

    switch(pedido_refrigerante.escolha)
    {
        case 1:
        printf("Quantas unidades de %s ? \n", pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um);
        scanf("%d", &pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade);

        printf("Escolha um tamanho: \n");
        printf(" 1 > ml %d \n 2 > l %d \n", refri_pequeno, refri_medio);
        scanf("%d", &pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);

            if (pedido_refrigerante.tamanho == refri_pequeno)
            {
                printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d ml\n", pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um, pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);

            }else{
                printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d \\l \n", pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um, pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);
            }
    }

    return (preco_total);
}

int menu ()
{
    int pedido_bebida;

    printf("+========================BEBIDAS=======================+\n");
    printf("|--------------- Escolha uma categoria: ---------------|\n");
    printf("|----------------- 1 > Refrigerantes ------------------|\n");
    printf("|---------------------- 2 > Sucos ---------------------|\n");
    printf("+======================================================|\n");
    printf("|-------------------- 0 > Cancelar --------------------|\n");
    printf("+======================================================+\n");

    scanf("%d", &pedido_bebida);

    switch(pedido_bebida)
    {
    case 1:
        refrigerante(pedido_bebida);
        break;

    case 2:

        break;

    case 0:

        break;

    default:

        break;

    }
return (pedido_bebida);
}

int main()
{

    menu();

    return 0;
}
```

```
main.c:19:20: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
  char pedido_um [] = "Cola Cola";
                    ^
main.c: In function ‘refrigerante’:
main.c:41:45: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘escolha’
             scanf("%d", &pedido_refrigerante.escolha);
                                             ^
main.c:43:28: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘escolha’
  switch(pedido_refrigerante.escolha)
                            ^
main.c:46:66: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘pedido_um’
         printf("Quantas unidades de %s ? \n", pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um);
                                                                  ^
main.c:47:41: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘quantidade_unidade’
         scanf("%d", &pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade);
                                         ^
main.c:51:41: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘tamanho’
         scanf("%d", &pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);
                                         ^
main.c:53:36: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘tamanho’
             if (pedido_refrigerante.tamanho == refri_pequeno)
                                    ^
main.c:55:85: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘quantidade_unidade’
                 printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d ml\n", pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um, pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);
                                                                                     ^
main.c:55:125: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘pedido_um’
                 printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d ml\n", pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um, pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);
                                                                                                                             ^
main.c:55:156: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘tamanho’
                 printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d ml\n", pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um, pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);
                                                                                                                                                            ^
main.c:58:87: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘quantidade_unidade’
                 printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d \\l \n", pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um, pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);
                                                                                       ^
main.c:58:127: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘pedido_um’
                 printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d \\l \n", pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um, pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);
                                                                                                                               ^
main.c:58:158: error: ‘struct refri’ has no member named ‘tamanho’
                 printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d \\l \n", pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um, pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
main.c:62:12: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     return (preco_total);
            ^
main.c: In function ‘menu’:
main.c:82:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘refrigerante’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         refrigerante(pedido_bebida);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:29:5: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 int refrigerante (int *preco_total)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Se o que você colocou em seus `define` forem valores numéricos então atente que em C utiliza-se "ponto decimal" e não "vírgula decimal". Talvez tenha ocorrido um erro de transcrição mas aqui: `char pedido_um [] = "Cola Cola;`faltou " fechando a string. Você definiu a função `int refrigerante (int *preco_total) {` como retornando um int mas está fazendo: `return (preco_total);` mas `preco_total` é um ponteiro para int e não um int.

Comment: Fechei a string com aspas mas ainda sim não consigo

Comment: Defina um tamanho fixo para a string e utilize a função strcpy para colocar um valor nesta string.

Comment: Estou vendo `pedido_um`, `pedido_dois` e `pedido_tres` dentro do seu `struct refri`. Isso significa que dentro de um refrigerante, temos três pedidos. Não acho que isso faça sentido.

Comment: Dentro da struct de refrigerantes tem tres tipos de refrigerantes possíveis

Comment: Note que existe uma diferença entre "definir uma estrutura" e "declarar variáveis do tipo estrutura". Você pode inicializar os componentes de uma variável do tipo estrutura ao declara-la. Ex. `struct point
  {
    int x, y;
  };
struct point first_point = { 5, 10 };`.

Comment: Eu peguei um erro, mas tem muitos, não faça um código inteiro cheio de erros, faça um detalhe, veja se deu certo, aí parta para o próximo. Quando está tudo errado a solução é jogar fora e começar de novo. Ou então conseguir que alguém dê uma solução pronta que não vai ensinar nada.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COCA_COLA_250 3.50
#define COCA_COLA_1000 8.00
#define FANTA_LARANJA_250 3.00
#define FANTA_LARANJA_1000 7.50
#define GUARANA_ANTARTIDA_250 3.50
#define GUARANA_ANTARTIDA_1000 8.00

#define MARACUJA_250 3.50
#define LIMONADA_250 3.00
#define LARANJA_250 3.00

struct refri
{
    char pedido_um[20];
    char pedido_dois[20];
    char pedido_tres[20];

    int escolha;
    int tamanho;
    int quantidade_unidade;

} pedido_refrigerante = {.pedido_um = "Coca Cola"};

int refrigerante(int *preco_total)
{
    int refri_pequeno = 250;
    int refri_medio = 1;

    printf("+===============================REFRIGERANTES==============================+\n");
    printf("|---------------------- Escolha o(s) refrigerante(s): ---------------------|\n");
    printf("|------- 1 > Coca Cola \t 2 > Guarana Antartida \t 3 > Fanta Laranja ------|\n");
    printf("+==========================================================================|\n");
    printf("|------------------------------ 0 > Cancelar ------------------------------|\n");
    printf("+==========================================================================+\n");

    scanf("%d", &pedido_refrigerante.escolha);

    switch (pedido_refrigerante.escolha)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Quantas unidades de %s ? \n", pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um);
        scanf("%d", &pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade);

        printf("Escolha um tamanho: \n");
        printf(" 1 > ml %d \n 2 > l %d \n", refri_pequeno, refri_medio);
        scanf("%d", &pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);

        if (pedido_refrigerante.tamanho == refri_pequeno)
        {
            printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d ml\n",
                   pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um,
                   pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Pedido de %d unidades de %s de %d \\l \n",
                   pedido_refrigerante.quantidade_unidade, pedido_refrigerante.pedido_um,
                   pedido_refrigerante.tamanho);
        }
    }

    return *preco_total;
}

int menu()
{
    int pedido_bebida;

    printf("+========================BEBIDAS=======================+\n");
    printf("|--------------- Escolha uma categoria: ---------------|\n");
    printf("|----------------- 1 > Refrigerantes ------------------|\n");
    printf("|---------------------- 2 > Sucos ---------------------|\n");
    printf("+======================================================|\n");
    printf("|-------------------- 0 > Cancelar --------------------|\n");
    printf("+======================================================+\n");

    scanf("%d", &pedido_bebida);

    switch (pedido_bebida)
    {
    case 1:
        refrigerante(&pedido_bebida);
        break;

    case 2:

        break;

    case 0:

        break;

    default:

        break;

    }

    return pedido_bebida;
}

int main()
{

    menu();

    return 0;
}
```

Não consegui entender o código, mas pelo menos removi os erros e avisos.

Comment: Não faça isso, depurar um código sem entender o seu significado, pois você poderá incorrer no mesmo erros das *IDEs* ao nos sugerir alterações absurdas em nosso código por não entenderem o que estamos fazendo. Não ajudou em nada o usuário, as dificuldades que tinha permanecem e na próxima construção de código os mesmos erros vão ressurgir.